# Date picker to only show month year

Tags: sharepoint-server, custom-form, datepicker

I have created an input form where the users are supposed to pick a date. But the users would like to only need to choose month and year as the specific date of the month is not relevant in this context.

Is it possible to customize the picker so you only need to choose a month and a year?

Answer (score 1):

**Unfortunately,** you can't customize The `Date Picker` to show only the Month and Year as OOTB.

**The alternative workarounds**

**(1)** Let the user select the normal date from the `Date Picker`, then create a `Calculated Column` to show only Month and year.

```
  =TEXT(Created,"MMMM")&" "&TEXT(Created,"yyyy")
```

**[Output]**

[image]

---

**(2)** Create 2 choice field one for Month (1-12) and one for the year, then create a `Calculated Column` to show the Month and Year as concatenated.

```
 = [Month] &" "& [Year]
```

**[Output]**

[image]

---

**(3)** Develop a custom Field type as mentioned at [Walkthrough: Creating a Custom Field Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb861799%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)